# Increase checkbox size - Phonegap Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing a quiz app using Phonegap, thus HTML, JavaScript & CSS - no other frameworks.  My issue is that the checkboxes appear very small on Android devices.  I tried setting the width & height of input[type=checkbox] to 2em in my CSS and this works in Chrome and the emulator, but not on actual devices (tested using a Samsung S4 Mini & Asus TF101).

The checkboxes are used inside an unordered list - here's the HTML:

```
<div class="challenge">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="opt0"><input type="checkbox" id="opt0" value="right">Answer A</label></li>
    <li><label for="opt1"><input type="checkbox" id="opt1" value="wrong">Answer B</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  font-family: arial;
  background-color:white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: medium;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.savvy_app {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  top: 73px;
  bottom: 2px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 98%;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
.challenge ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.challenge ul li, .results ul li {
  font-family: georgia;
  font-weight: normal;      
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.challenge label, .results label {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.challenge input, .results input {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` for checkbox

Comment: No, I need the checkboxes displayed to allow users the select possible answers to the quiz.  Questions are multiple choice and have more than one answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience form elements are a nightmare to style reliably across all devices, particularly checkboxes and radio buttons.

One solution is to set the checkboxes' visibility to hidden or opacity to 0 and then use some CSS such as `input[type=checkbox]:checked` to change the background image of a span next to the checkbox. Your background image can then consist of a 2 state checkbox drawn however you want it to look.

There are lots of compatibility and accessibility issues surrounding this - it's debatable whether it's worth while.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my major concern with this solution is cross platform compatibility (plan is to eventually port the app to IOS devices) and additional overhead on performance .

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't a reliable cross platform method of styling checkboxes